# Single condition on multiple columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have to apply one condition on multiple columns in case statement(alternative is also good)

```
CASE 
    WHEN lower(descr) LIKE '%Apple%'
        THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN lower(category) LIKE '%Apple%'
        THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN lower(request_desc) LIKE '%Apple%'
        THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN lower(resolve_text) LIKE '%Apple%'
        THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
    END AS Apple_Flag
```

So basically I am checking Apple in all four columns, is there any better way to write this...

Comment: You can start with replacing `Apple` with `apple` as `lower` conversiom implies. Btw, the better option doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat shorter code  (presuming that any column should contain `apple` so that result is "Yes") would be

```
case when lower(descr)        like '%apple%' or 
          lower(category)     like '%apple%' or
          lower(request_desc) like '%apple%' or
          lower(resolve_text) like '%apple%'
     then 'Yes'
     else 'No'
end as apple_flag
```

or even

```
case when lower(descr||'!'||category||'!'||request_desc||'!'||resolve_text) like '%apple%'
     then 'Yes'
     else 'No'
end as apple_flag
```

(Of course, by using lower `apple` in condition, not `Apple` as you did).

---

If this:

> I am checking Apple in all four columns

means that all 4 column should contain `apple`, then change `or` to `and`.

Comment: Concatenation should contain some separator to exclude false positives

Comment: It should; thank you, @astentx.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the already suggested improvements, another strategy would be to use ORACLE TEXT with a MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE if the searching in these columns is an important part of the application with strong speed requirements, if not it may be overkilling.